# Android Menu Listener

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, event-handling, onclick

I am new to Java and Android development and I am trying to use event handlers for menus. I had no problems setting up the menus in xml, but now I am confused on how to use handlers.

I am using

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

and I only know how to create new activities, eg:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,About.class))
```

I've seen many tutorials but they all focus on buttons, which I tried and failed.
Also, can I have methods in different classes to better organize my code?
For example have method1.java, method2.java, method3.java,.... and instantiate these classes to call on the methods.

If it helps, what I am trying to do is use OpenGL and allow the user to be able to rotate, translate, resize, etc depending on the menu option selected.

EDIT: I am trying to use states for my program, and only be able to use the handlers defined for the given states.

Answer (score 3):

In the menu xml file, each item has an id, example...

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/reset"
  android:title="@string/gla_menu_title_reset" />
```

In your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` handler you need to get the id of the item that is passed in and then process it. An easy way of doing this is with a switch / case...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.reset:
            // Do something
            return true;
        case R.id.something_else:
            ...
            return true;
     }
}
```

And, yes, you can create standard Java classes in Android.

Comment: Yes, I did this part. The confusing part is what will go in each case. What I am trying to achieve is for each case, switch to different states. Each state will have its own set of methods and event handlers.